# Can "not only ... but also" be constructed as "not only ... as also"?

Tags: inversion

In other languages, the construction "[not only ... but also](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/not-only-but-also)" can be constructed in a different form: "not only ... as also".

Is this also possible in English? For example, is this sentence correct?:

> Not only a solution is possible as, in due time, inevitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. At least, it's not grammatical as an exact substitute. (And your example as given is not grammatical).

The best form of your example would be:

> Not only is a solution possible but it is, in due time, inevitable.

If you *really* wanted to use `as` you would more likely write (e.g.):

> A solution should be forthcoming soon, as it is inevitable that we will see one.

But I'd stick with the "not only but also" pattern here.